# How do I cycle images in ONE picturebox using the mousewheel?

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am making a simple game that the user selects two weapons (primary and secondary). In the game window the weapon is displayed in a picturebox (picWeapon) in the corner of the screen.  I want the user to be able to scroll up (or down since there's only one other weapon) to select the secondary weapon.  What code to I place to cycle through images using the mouse wheel?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private isPrimary As Boolean = True 'assumes the Primary image is already loaded
Private Sub Form1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
    If e.Delta > 0 And isPrimary = False Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Scrolled up!")
        PicWeapon.Load(filepathOfPrimary)
        isPrimary = True
    ElseIF isPrimary = True Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Scrolled down!")
        PicWeapon.Load(filepathOfSecondary)
        isPrimary = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It can't be the PicWeapon's event.  The MouseWheel event is sent to the window with the focus, not the one that's hovered, a PictureBox can't receive the focus.  More code is needed to find out where the cursor is located.

Comment: and suppose they selected one weapon from a drop down of 3 on the previous page?  How would I load the primary image and assign it as that type of weapon?  What I had in mind was (in the select case of the drop down) to put: Dim selectedWeapon as image.   then just insert "selectedWeapon" into the picweapon.load(selectedweapon) right?